# When can I ask questions again in Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?  (the answer is here, in this post)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)

Sorry, I have been a pain for the site but then I have improved on answer quality and have even raised a bounty for certain question.

Now, it's been months since I last posted a question. Should I move on to find another site which might help me to answer my questions?

Comment: You're still getting the "sorry, we're no longer accepting questions" message? I'm a bit surprised if you are, after looking at your account.

Comment: Yes, i still get the same message

Comment: What's the problem man @TimPost:

Comment: Please wait a few minutes before posting "gimme answer"... Tim might be in the bathroom or having dinner or is in some other way away from his screen.

Comment: You were on the edge; I threw you an upvote, and you can ask again now. Be sure to watch your question quality in the future.

Comment: Glad to see someone actually took our advice and tried to improve. Thanks, @balpha :)

Comment: Thanks :) 
Improving really pays

Comment: Some one's Jealous @MrLister:

Comment: But still now i been blocked from Meta Stackoverflow

Comment: Nice that balpha got your account enabled again, but please take care of some basic English rules. When referring to yourself, "I" is always uppercased, like "I am", not "i am". And please take care about punctuation, like dots, and like a space after a comma but not before it. And you get a new paragraph by using a blank line; just pressing Return is not enough. To make myself clear, I've edited a bit; see [the revision history](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/135231/revisions) for the minor changes I made that really make things look better, I feel. Success!